# Volume can't be increased via keyboard volume knob after suspend

Tags: audio, keyboard, pulseaudio, suspend, audio-volume

Below is pavucontrol GUI. As you can see, volume is 100%.

I can use the knob of my Roccat external keyboard, to change it to any value between 0% and 100%.

Now I do the following

- set it to something lower than 100%, say 69%,
- suspend the system via `systemctl suspend`
- wake the system up

At this point, the keyboard knob will allow me to reduce the volume below 69%, ***but not increase it above 69%***.

I can pull up the volume to 100% using pavucontrol, at which point the knob can again span the whole 0-100% range.

Why is that the case? And how can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the knob was working because of a configuration done in the context of the i3 window manager that I use, and long long ago I had botched the configuration.

These are the culprits:

```
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec amixer -q set Master 1%+ unmute && pkill -RTMIN+1 i3blocks
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec amixer -q set Master 1%- unmute && pkill -RTMIN+1 i3blocks
```

which need to be changed to this

```
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec amixer -q -D pulse set Master 1%+ unmute && pkill -RTMIN+1 i3blocks
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec amixer -q -D pulse set Master 1%- unmute && pkill -RTMIN+1 i3blocks
```

i.e. by passing `-D pulse` to `amixer`. The idea came from [line 112](https://github.com/vivien/i3blocks-contrib/blob/master/volume-pulseaudio/volume-pulseaudio#L112) of [the code of the `volume-pulseaudio` i3 custom blocklet](https://github.com/vivien/i3blocks-contrib/blob/master/volume-pulseaudio/volume-pulseaudio).

Not sure what the difference is between `set` and `sset` for `amxier`. From `man amixer` I deduce they are synonymous. And that also `get` and `sget` are synonymous with each other.